# Erro no IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Rotas.Models
{
    public class Noticia
    {
        public class Noticia
        {
            public int NoticiaId { get; set; }
            public string Titulo { get; set; }
            public string Conteudo { get; set; }
            public string Categoria { get; set; }
            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
            public DateTime Data { get; set; }
            /* Cria uma array do tipo IEnumerable que é mais sofisticado e que joga um tanto de objetos do tipo Noticia dentro*/
            public IEnumerable<Noticia> TodasAsNoticias()
            {

                // instancia uma coleção de noticias
                var retorno = new Collection<Noticia>
                {
                    new Noticia
                        {
                            NoticiaId = 1,
                            Categoria = "Esportes",
                            Titulo = "Felipe Massa ganha F1",
                            Conteudo = "Numa tarde de chuva Felipe Massa ganha F1 no Brasil...",
                            Data = new DateTime(2012,7,5)


                        },
                    new Noticia
                        {
                            NoticiaId = 2,
                            Categoria = "Política",
                            Titulo = "Presidente assina convênios",
                            Conteudo = "Durante reunião o presidente Ismael Freitas assinou os convênios...",
                            Data = new DateTime(2012,7,3)
                        },
                    new Noticia
                        {
                            NoticiaId = 3,
                            Categoria = "Política",
                            Titulo = "Vereador é eleito pela 4ª vez",
                            Conteudo = "Vereador Fabio Pratt é eleito pela quarta vez...",
                            Data = new DateTime(2012,7,20)
                        },
                    new Noticia
                        {
                            NoticiaId = 4,
                            Categoria = "Esportes",
                            Titulo = "O tão sonhado titulo chegou",
                            Conteudo = "Em um jogo que levou os torcedores ao delirio...",
                            Data = new DateTime(2012,7,18)
                        },
                    new Noticia
                        {
                            NoticiaId = 5,
                            Categoria = "Humor",
                            Titulo = "O Comediante Anderson Renato fará shou hoje",
                            Conteudo = "O comediante mais engraçados dos comentários do Youtube fará show...",
                            Data = new DateTime(2012,7,14)
                        },
                    new Noticia
                        {
                            NoticiaId = 6,
                            Categoria = "Policial",
                            Titulo = "Tenente coronel Lucas Farias Santos assume o controle",
                            Conteudo = "Durante a retomada do morro o tenente coronel disse...",
                            Data = new DateTime(2012,7,19)
                        },
                    new Noticia
                        {
                            NoticiaId = 7,
                            Categoria = "Esportes",
                            Titulo = "Atacante do Barcelona faz 4 gols",
                            Conteudo = "O atacante Lucas Farias Santos Messi, fez 4 gols e decidiu o titulo...",
                            Data = new DateTime(2012,7,8)
                        }
                };
                return retorno;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A classe Noticia é estática? Qual o código de "Rotas"?

Comment: Rotas é o nome do projeto, ela nao é estatica

Comment: Por favor, poste o código em texto, não imagens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem uma bagunça aí. Você declara duas vezes a classe **`Noticia`**, uma dentro da outra.

Remova a declaração mais externa, deixando o código assim:

```
namespace Rotas.Model 
{
    public class Noticia 
    {
        // Membros da classe 

        public IEnumerable<Noticia> TodasAsNoticias()
        {
            // Todo o código do método
        }
    }
}
```

No controller, faltam os parênteses para inicializar a classe

```
todasAsNoticias = new Noticia().TodasAsNoticias().OrderByDescending(x => x.Data);
```

Note que este método **poderia ser estático**. Desta forma, não seria neessário criar uma instância da classe para chamá-lo, já que não é preciso uma instância de notícia, acho que é muito mais sensato criar o método sendo estático.

A chamada ficaria assim

```
todasAsNoticias = new Noticia.TodasAsNoticias().OrderByDescending(x => x.Data);
```

Comment: Sim agora que postei o codigo eu consegui ver rsrsrs obrigado !

Answer (score 2):

Faltou um set de parentesis na construção do objeto `Noticia`:

```
todasAsNoticias = new Noticia.TodasAsNoticias().OrderByDescending(x => x.Data);
```

Deveria ser:

```
todasAsNoticias = new Noticia().TodasAsNoticias().OrderByDescending(x => x.Data);
```

**Edição 1**

Também segundo a sua imagem, você criou uma classe `Noticia`... dentro de uma outra classe `Notícia`:

```
public class Noticia 
{
  public class Noticia 
  {
    public IEnumerable<Noticia> TodasAsNoticias()
    {
      // Implementação...
    }
  }
}
```

Quando provalmente você quis dizer:

```
public class Noticia 
{
  public IEnumerable<Noticia> TodasAsNoticias()
  {
    // Implementação...
  }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'Rotas.Models.Noticia' does not contain a definition for 'TodasAsNoticias' and no extension method 'TodasAsNoticias' accepting a first argument of type 'Rotas.Models.Noticia' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Agora da esse erro

Comment: `TodasAsNoticias` é um método de instância da classe `Noticia`?

Comment: Sim sim, TodasAsNoticias esta no model(classe Noticia)

Comment: @ThalesSilveira nesse caso não deveria dar este erro. Pode editar a sua pergunta e adicionar a classe `Noticia` inteira?

Comment: Você poderia postar o código completo da classe Noticia?

Comment: @Genos pronto editei, da uma olhada